# Prove for all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x+y \le (4xy)/(x+y)$, then $x=y$

Tags: inequality, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Would a direct or indirect proof be appropriate for this theorem?

Comment: What have you tried? Eliminating the denominator and collecting everything on one side could be a good start.

Comment: With problems like these, where you have a very concrete algebraic equality/unequality, you shouldn't think "should I use contradiction, or contrapositive, etc". You should just try to play around with it algebraically until you perhaps solve it; if that doesn't work, THEN you should maybe consider looking for some more abstract sort of proof

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full problem statement.  When the title alone is used to state the problem setup and goal, brevity risks confusion for your Readers.  Including a reasonably self-contained problem statement in the body gives you the opportunity to share more context, such as why the problem is important to you or what difficulty your approach ran into.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x+y>0$, then we obtain

$$ (x+y)^2 \leq 4xy $$

as was pointed out by the Doc

Therefore,

$$ x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \leq 4xy $$

which implies that

$$ x^2+y^2 \leq 2xy $$

which implies that

$$ x^2-2xy +y^2 \leq 0 $$

and so we get

$$ 0 \leq (x-y)^2 \leq 0$$

$x-y$ better be $0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiplying by $$x+y>0$$ we get $$(x+y)^2\le 4xy$$ can you finish?

Comment: Yes! For some reason I was thinking a direct proof wasn't the best route but I was overthinking. Thank you

Comment: The last line can be written as $$(x-y)^2\le 0$$